# How to handle server to server communication for a multi-tenant rest api?

Tags: rest, security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

Service B is a restful multi-tenant API.

Service A is a service that needs to do work on behalf of any tenant.

What do you recommend for authenticating/authorizing A -> B communication?

Current setup for Service B (the restful API): All data is in one database and one schema with tenant id column in each table.  We use oauth 2 to give users access tokens after a form login.  The access token includes a claim that has their tenant id.  When users make requests, we figure out their tenant id from the claim, and add that tenant id as part of a "where" clause to retrieve only their data.

Now say that service A needs to do some work for tenant "foo."  The naive approach is to have service A login as a user that is associated with tenant "foo" and send that access token.

Any better approaches?

Comment: If you are already using oauth2, couldn't service A just get a "proper" ticket through oauth to access service B on the user's behalf?

Comment: Yes, that's what we are doing now.  But it means each time Service A needs to do work for a different tenant, it needs to get a new token.  Ideally, I would want it to get one token and just have authorization to access any data from any tenant.  It's looking like the client credential flow might be what I want... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4

Answer (score 1):

> Client Credentials Flow

I would agree that this seems to fit.
Providing that Service A (the client) has the right to access the data from Service B (the resource server) without explicit user consent.

For example, if service A and B both "own" the data then the client, service A, is effectively an internal client.

If service A is a 3rd party, then you're in a grey area if you are returning user level data.

Assuming also that service B would not be dependent on the tenant ID and user ID as a claim in the token for the endpoints to work correctly.

> Resource Owner Password flow

If you own the identity server you could create a special user account for each tenant in the user database and service A could use the Resource Owner Password flow (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-9) and supply the special user and password to the Authorisation server to get a token and tenant ID without a need for a login. I've seen this done but I don't like or recommend it!

Comment: Yes, this will be an internal client.  Both own the data.  "Assuming also that service A would provide the tenant ID as a claim in the token..."  Doing this would mean that service A would need to get a new token every time it does work for a different tenant.  I was thinking about adding the tenant id as a separate header or as part of the url to avoid this.  Thoughts?

Comment: You're right - not sure why I added that as I actually mean practically the opposite! I will edit answer. If you can change the api to allow the tenant id to be a part of the endpoint message, or process it from an http header, you will have the 1 token scenario you want.